# Strapi.io Controller.find().exec(...)

Tags: javascript, strapi

I try to use the controller.find().exec(...) method and under the exec callback function I try to create the body content. But I have no idea what should I do. I think I have to use the yield keyword there but it drops an error if I try to use yield in the callback function. My code looks something like this:

```
let value;
Firstcontroller.find().exec(function (error, result) {
    value = yield result;
});
this.body = value;
```

I already tried with yield and without, with let and without. And some of the options. Please let me share if you have any idea. I have to use exec because I have to use the result and pass it to a different find method.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
// Retrieve the value
const value = yield Firstcontroller.find();

// Set the value to the body
this.body = value;
```

Comment: Like I said, I have to use exec, because I have to work with the output.

Comment: `value` object is the output here. You can work with it.

Comment: Nope,  I can't,  already tried this. What I want is to call the find method for a different controller and restrict the I'd based on the last find output. That's why I need to use exec.